# Filthy Rich Clients - Problem with propertySetter in ObjectModifier

Tags: java

I'm trying to use the Animator class from the framework, from inside my JFrame I do:

```
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    super.mouseClicked(e);
    Animator animator = new Animator(100);
    animator.addTarget(new PropertySetter(AnimatedIcon.this, "alpha", 0.0f));
    animator.setAcceleration(0.2f);
    animator.setDeceleration(0.4f);
    animator.start();
}
});
```

But as a result I get the following error:
"Problem with propertySetter in ObjectModifier
Problem invoking method in `setValue:java.lang.NullPointerException`"
Please help, I tried many things to resolve it, without success.
(AnimatedIcon is an outer class)

Comment: You've got an extra `});` in your example code.

Comment: What line throws this exception?

Comment: animator.start();
throws the exception. (It is not printed as an exception, but as a simple System.out.ptint(...); So there is no stack to look into.)

Comment: Is Animator your class? Do you have the code for it?

Comment: No, the Animator is the Framework's class, from Timing Framework. (Developed by the Romain Guy)

Comment: You could give a link to this framework, this would help for helpers who don't know it.

Comment: Here is the link for the framework: [link](http://timingframework.dev.java.net) and this is the site of the book itself with the examples: [link](http://filthyrichclients.org) . Similar code appears under Chapter 17 "Dynamic Effects", "Fading".

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
super.mouseClicked(e);

PropertySetter setter = new PropertySetter(AnimatedIcon.this, "alpha", 0.0f));
Animator animator = new Animator(100, setter);
animator.setAcceleration(0.2f);
animator.setDeceleration(0.4f);
animator.start();
```

Comment: By reading the source code for `PropertySetter` class, it seems like you are missing `setAlpha(..)` from `AnimatedIcon` class. Can you confirm you have that API in that class?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, I found out my mistake: the class was not declared as public, but as default instead. Since I'm working with framework that use annotations, and the framework is not from the same package, the non-public class did not allow to use its' methods from the outside.